# Set Yes/No field on selected list items by clicking a button

Tags: javascript

The functions I need are not  complex but I did not succeded to make it work on my sharepoint, hence my posting here.

I have a list of items and a Yes/No column. I want that the user get the possibility to select multiple items and by clicking a button to set the Y/N column to yes for theses selected items.

So far I have this code that manage to get the IDs of the element selected but I dont succeed to update the Y/N field using these IDs.

At the moment, the code is into a Script Editor above my grouped list.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function SetToYes() {
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems  = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
var mySeletedItems = '';
var i;

 for (i in selectedItems )
 {
      mySeletedItems += '|' + selectedItems [i].id; // '+= means x += y same as x = x + y
 // I think setting the value of the Y/N field shall happen here using the id of the field selected selectedItems [i].id
 }
alert (mySeletedItems); //just for me to see that the code works properly
}
</script>

<html>
<input id="GetIDselected" type="button" value="Get ID of selected items" onclick="SetToYes();"></input>
</html>
```

I tried with ctx.currentitem or selecteItems[i].nameOfmyYNfield but no luck so far.

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, new day, new code.
I am now using that one to do the update of my Yes/No field but there is an error at the update(). Else I manage to get the item I want (at the moment locked on ID=2 for conveniance) and to read the Yes/No field value.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var itemId = 2;
var targetListItem;

function SetToYes() {
     var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
     var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Reporting Level 1+2');
     targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
     clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS');
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
   function onQuerySucceeded() {
       var ListItem;
       alert('Request succeeded. \n\nRetrieved Item is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS'));
        //targetListItem['Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS']="1";
       targetListItem.set_item('Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS',true);
       targetListItem.Update();
   }
   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
     alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }
</script>

<input id="GetIDselected" type="button" value="Get ID of selected items" onclick="SetToYes();"></input>
```

The console log tell me the update() method is not allowed on my variable "targetListItem" and I dont get why when I compare to other update scripts found on internet. Any clues?

**EDIT2:**
My final working code, with 2 buttons. 1 to mark as yes, the other as no. It might be usefull to others in the futur.

the last code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var targetListItem;

function SetToECNOPS(YesOrNo){
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems  = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Reporting Level 1+2');
    var itemArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {            

        targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
        targetListItem.set_item('Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS',YesOrNo);
        targetListItem.update();
        itemArray[i] = targetListItem;
        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
    }    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        console.log("success update");
    },function(){
        console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
//refresh page to see the changes
window.parent.location.href = window.location.href;
}
</script>

<input id="SeToYes" type="button" value="Add to ECN OPS" onclick="SetToECNOPS(1);"></input>
<input id="SetToNo" type="button" value="Remove from ECN OPS" onclick="SetToECNOPS(0);"></input>
```

Comment: First learn to **not** use ``alert`` and do proper development using the F12 console... You are now trying to cycle on the Highway.... *you will get killed*

Comment: I know I schould use console.log or a dialog, but as far as I know, the alert is not hurting the code as I debugg it. Later they will of course be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have modified your code, you need to update it as below.

Couple of things, get rid of `alert` and `function.createdelegate`

```
var itemId = 2;
var targetListItem;

function SetToYes() {
     var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
     var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Reporting Level 1+2');
     targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
     targetListItem.set_item('Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS',1);
     targetListItem.update();     
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            console.log("success update");
     },function(sender, args){
        console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
     });
}
```

Now, to update selected list items, you can use the below code:

```
function SetToYes(){
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems  = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Reporting Level 1+2');
    var itemArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {            

        targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
        targetListItem.set_item('Topic_x0020_ECN_x0020_OPS',1);
        targetListItem.update();
        itemArray[i] = targetListItem;
        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
    }    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        console.log("success update");
    },function(sender, args){
        console.log('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
}
```

Comment: @Romain - my bad, to set the yes/no field, you need to set the value as `1 or 0`. So, to set value, it needs to be `targetListItem.set_item('YesNoFieldInternalName', 1);` , have updated code accordingly

Comment: thanks for your answer, I try to implement it now but console says oListItem is not defined (itemArray[i] = oListItem;). it need to be replaced by targetListItem I assume?

Comment: Have updated the code, can you check now ? Yes, you are correct, my bad, sorry

Comment: Yes, it works! Now I just need to refresh my list after the update but I think I will easily find the needed code. Thanks a lot for your support Gautem!! By the way, can you shortly explain what does "itemArray[i]"?

Comment: welcome , glad i could help :)

Comment: Cant really say for sure, but have added `args` in the failure method. So probably will help you identify the error. Also, `input` is self closing, so your html should be `<input id="SeToYes" type="button" value="Add to ECN OPS" onclick="SetToECNOPS(1);" />` , but other than that can't pinpoint the error.